# What's another word for 'centre' that starts with the letter 'S'?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

> **Centre** - (noun) the point from which an activity or process is
>   directed, or on which it is focused. Like a shopping centre, sports
>   centre, etc.

I'm looking for another word for it but starts with a letter "S". So far just able to come up with 'stage' but it seems a bit far off.

Comment: I would suggest 'source' as *the point from which an activity or process is directed*.

Comment: Well, given your example, there's always "supermarket".

Comment: @HotLicks, supermarket will take up the whole meaning of 'shopping centre'. I'm looking for the 'centre' part only.

Comment: I posted an answer, but what about *Station*?

Comment: @Meed A "stadium?"

Comment: Station sounds good @JHCL

Comment: Stadium is not bad either. Sounds grand @Elian. Let's wait for other suggestions.

Comment: @Meed How about "square?"

Comment: @Elian you suggested 'stade' just now didn't you? I went to check it out as I've never really heard anyone using it.

Comment: @Meed Yes, it's a rare synonym for "stadium." http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stade

Comment: Yes, i'm considering that actually as it sounds less 'grand' than stadium. Was just wondering why did you delete it?

Comment: *Switchboard* has been used metaphorically for this purpose.

Comment: If you want to give a shopping district the open-air central market/bazaar feeling with a crowded middle eastern flavour - there is always "Souk".

Comment: @Meed How about "strip," i.e. an area, as along a busy street or highway, that is lined with a great number and variety of commercial facilities?.

Comment: Are you constrained to "real" words? I mean, if you are starting with the letter"S" for alliterative reasons for a proper name (the Syracuse S___) then you open up options. For example, in Ottawa we have a multi-function recreation complex (skating, olympic pool, football pitch, gymnasium, basketball, squash, etc) called the "Sportsplex". Not a real word but it works as a descriptive proper name for the location. For Stade, the only places I've seen that used are in French regions, e.g. Montreal's Stade Olympique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like a [**seat**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/seat) (e.g. of administration or government):

> A principal site or location: *Parliament House was the seat of the Scots Parliament until the Union with England* (-- Oxford Dictionaries Online)

Answer (score 0):

A "**section**" is broadly, a distinct part of a thing. It expresses  *centre's* sense of focus, but with the implication of being apart of `x`. The grandness it conveys depends on what `it` is a section of.

Per *[dictionary.com:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/section)*

> a distinct part or subdivision of anything, as an object, country, community, class, or the like.

- "shopping center" → "shopping section"
- "residential center" → "residential section"